# REACT: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.flights.forEach is not a function

Tags: java, rest, reactjs

I am trying to learn React, and I stumbled upon the error from the title in my program. Here is my code:

```
class FlightRow extends React.Component{

handleClicke=(event)=>{
    console.log('delete button pentru '+this.props.flight.flightId);
    this.props.deleteFunc(this.props.flight.flightId);
}

render() {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.flight.flightId}</td>
            <td>{this.props.flight.destination}</td>
            <td>{this.props.flight.airport}</td>
            <td>{this.props.flight.freeseats}</td>
            <td>{this.props.flight.datehour}</td>
            <td><button  onClick={this.handleClicke}>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    );
}
}

class FlightTable extends React.Component {
render() {
    var rows = [];
    var functieStergere=this.props.deleteFunc;
    this.props.flights.forEach(function(flight) {

        rows.push(<FlightRow flight={flight} key={flight.flightId} deleteFunc={functieStergere} />);
    });
    return (<div className="FlightTable">

        <table className="center">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FlightId</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Airport</th>
                <th>Freeseats</th>
                <th>Datehour</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export default FlightTable;
```

I am getting the error in the first lines of the FlightTable class, when I am trying to fill it. Immediately after I start the app, I see for like one second the table filled exactly how it should be, then I receive the error.

Here is where I declare my "flights" array.

```
class FlightApp extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={flights:[{"flightId":12,"destination":"CCCCC","airport":"AAAAA","freeseats":100,"datehour":"2017-02-02"},{"flightId":13,"destination":"CCCCC","airport":"AAAAA","freeseats":100,"datehour":"2017-02-02"}],
        deleteFunc:this.deleteFunc.bind(this),
        addFunc:this.addFunc.bind(this),
    }
    console.log('FlightApp constructor')
}

addFunc(flight){
    console.log('inside add Func '+flight);
    AddFlight(flight)
        .then(res=> GetFlights())
        .then(flights=>this.setState({flights}))
        .catch(erorr=>console.log('eroare add ',erorr));
}


deleteFunc(flight){
    console.log('inside deleteFunc '+flight);
    DeleteFlight(flight)
        .then(res=> GetFlights())
        .then(flights=>this.setState({flights}))
        .catch(error=>console.log('eroare delete', error));
}


componentDidMount(){
    console.log('inside componentDidMount')
    GetFlights().then(flights=>this.setState({flights}));
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="FlightApp">
            <h1>Flight Management</h1>
            <FlightForm addFunc={this.state.addFunc}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
             <FlightTable flights={this.state.flights} deleteFunc={this.state.deleteFunc}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default FlightApp;
```

The "GetFlights()" method looks like this, and it calls a method from a Java REST Spring Server that return a List

```
export function GetFlights(){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
var myInit = { method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'cors'};
var request = new Request(CHAT_USERS_BASE_URL, myInit);
console.log('Inainte de fetch pentru '+CHAT_USERS_BASE_URL)
return fetch(request)
    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(data=> {
         console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
         return data;
     }).catch(error=>{
            console.log('Request failed', error);
            return error;
      });

}
```

How could I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your API is not returning an array. What is the output of `console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);` ??

Comment: Apart from the question, you have set the bound functions inside your `FlightApp` state which is not right. The bound functions should be outside. What is the need to have them in state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this error I had and now everything works good. In my Spring Controller, I added as an annotation *@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")*, and now everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the response you receive from the server? I believe it's not an array which is leading to this error. Post the response received from the server.